# Loading "window.open" command on IOS devices only.....?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

my first endeavor at building a site to accomodate IOS, and it's not going well.

embedding a flickr slideshow as an object on the page. works fine on regular browsers, not so much on iPad (obviously, because it's flash.) - nothing loads but the background image.

have a decent workaround, which is to make the cell itself a link, that opens a new browser window with the flickr page itself. perfect on the iPad.  But on regular browsers clicking on the flickr object produces both actions - slideshow AND new window with flickr page.

what i need is to script it in such a way that **only** the IOS will see this instruction:

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.flickr.com//photos/72076640@N04/sets/72157628873638463/show/');"
```

here's the page in question:

```
http://creyoncafe.com/pages/galeria2.html
```

Can anybody help?

(Hope I was clear. Sorry if i went on too long... was following the edict to be as specific as possible. )

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript function to the page like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showFlickr () {

        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        if (userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 ||
            userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1 ||
            userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1) {
            window.open('http://www.flickr.com//photos/72076640@N04/sets/72157628873638463/show/');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Then in your onclick just say

```
onclick="return showFlickr()"
```

This is by no means the most elegant solution, but it should work.

A better approach would be to find a script that detects whether Flash is enabled on the browser and use that to decide which type of gallery to show. There are plenty of non-iOS devices that cannot display Flash either, such as desktop machines without Flash or with Flash blockers installed, or other brands of smartphone, such as older Android devices, Windows Phone, Blackberries, etc. Using the user agent will never handle every device, but detecting Flash should work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `onclick` handlers to

```
onclick="if (!/(iPhone|iPad).*Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent)) return true; window.open('http://www.flickr.com//photos/72076640@N04/sets/72157628873638463/show/'); return false;"
```